# How to change displayed html of tag links?

Tags: wordpress

By default, tags in WordPress front-end look this way:

```
<a href=".../tag_URL">Name of the tag</a>
```

I want to change text in the *Name of the tag* part for all tags that are used on pages with my custom template. How to achieve this?

Comment: Are you familiar with using [WordPress hooks](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/hooks/)? The hook that should help you is the [tag_link](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/tag_link/) filter hook. You can receive the tag link HTML that WordPress creates by default, and modify it before it is sent to the browser.